# apache2-mpm-worker missing in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apache2.4

I would like to install apache2-mpm-worker on Ubuntu 16.04, but it looks that this package is not avalaible for ubuntu 16.04.
Do you have somebody any information why this important package is missing in xenial repository?

Comment: Does the answer work for you?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no **apache2-mpm-worker** package because the **mpm_worker** module is included by default when you install Apache on 16.04. It is contained in the **apache2-bin** package that is a dependency of **apache2**:

```
> dpkg -L apache2-bin | grep mpm
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_event.so
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_worker.so
```

**mpm_event** is enabled by default, so to enable **mpm_worker**:

```
sudo a2dismod mpm_event
sudo a2enmod mpm_worker
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and sorry for delay !