# What is the way to enable MPM worker/event in Ubuntu 16?

Tags: 16.10

When I do as per this: [apache2-mpm-worker missing in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/808556/apache2-mpm-worker-missing-in-ubuntu-16-04)

The Apache server isn't restarting and givin this error in the syslog:

```
May  3 13:53:57 host apache2[15732]: [Fri May 03 13:53:57.270545 2019] [:crit] [pid 15741:tid 139828766218112] Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe.  You need to recompile PHP.
```

Is there is Ubuntu image wherein these `worker/event` MPM modes are readily available?

Mine is default installation Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

`apache2 -v` shows:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2017-07-27T14:34:01
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/453377/how-to-enable-event-mpm-apache-2-4-on-s there is Ubuntu image wherein these worker/event MPM modes are readily available?": wrong question ;-) see the link on how to do this. Adjust for the php version where needed ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind the linked answer does not work in my case